# Jenkins slave is not using ccache

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, jenkins

My Jenkins connects to its slave (Ubuntu) via SSH. I followed all possible instructions on installing ccache on the slave, I put "export USE_CCACHE=1" in every possible place, I have linked compilers so on "which gcc" I have "/usr/lib/ccache/gcc", but while building android ROM on that slave ccache is not used. Dir ~/.ccache always has the same size (didn't set CCACHE_DIR, so using default location, and ccache size is 50G).

How do I make it use ccache?

Answer (score 1):

Android programs run on different architecture than your computer, so they are not compiled by your standard gcc, but are cross-compiled. You must find settings for your cross-compiler or android platform tools and add it there. 
I had to edit ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/core/default-build-commands.mk and add ccache to compiler configuration to start using ccache.

Was following this howto:
[How to use ccache to speed up android compilation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_use_CCache_to_speed_up_cocos2d-x_android_compilation)

That is for compilation of application not ROM, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted; seems okay to me.